# Tensorflow Object Detection, Writing detected object to console output

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Working on a project called tensorflow object detection and I am able to detect objects.

I want to write to console output the object I detect.

The main problem is I don't know where the variable that holds name of the object.

"This is the link I watch"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U

"This is the image I detect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIqHd.png)

```
img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
image_np = np.array(img)

input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
              for key, value in detections.items()}
detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

# detection_classes should be ints.
detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np_with_detections,
            detections['detection_boxes'],
            detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
            detections['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            max_boxes_to_draw=5,
            min_score_thresh=.8,
            agnostic_mode=False)

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_np_with_detections, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```